# Result of GET of specified data from mysql using expressjs and xmlhttprequest undefined?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get all data from the specified id of MySQL using node js with the express framework and XMLHttpRequest from the front-end side(HTML)

> Node Js code:

```
app.get('/api/props/:id',(req,res)=>{
    let sql = "SELECT * from crud WHERE id='"+parseInt(req.params.id)+"'";
    con.query(sql, (err,results) =>{
        if(err) throw err
        console.log("GET ACCOUNT ID: '"+req.params.id+"' NOW !");
        return res.send(results);
    })
})
```

> Javascript code in HTML:

```
function searchProps() {
    var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/props";
    let prop_data = {}
    prop_data.id = document.getElementById('searchProp').value;
    var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var content = "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Prop Title</th><td>prop_address</td><td>prop_neighbor</td><td>country</td><td>state</td><td>city</td><td>zip</td><td>prop_type</td><td>prop_status</td><td>price</td><td>list_info</td></tr>";
    xhr.open('GET', url+"/"+prop_data.id, true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
                content += "<tr><td>" + data.id + "</td><td>" + data.prop_title + "</td><td>" + data.prop_address + "</td><td>" + data.prop_neighborhood + "</td><td>" + data.country + "</td><td>" + data.state + "</td><td>" + data.city + "</td><td>" + data.zip + "</td><td>" + data.prop_type + "</td><td>" + data.prop_status + "</td><td>" + data.price + "</td><td>" + data.list_info + "</td></tr>";
            document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = content;
        } else {
            console.error(props);
        }
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

The result would be all undefined while, on the other hand, I use to get for all data without specifying a certain id and result comes up based on the MySQL database.

*Note: I also tried to use POSTMAN and the result comes up according to the database with no error but when using XMLHTTPRequest the value will be undefined.

Do you guys have any suggestions for the solution?

Comment: Have you tried using fetch() instead of XMLHttpRequest?

This tutorial made it make sense for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc8DU14qX6I&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6YxDKpFzf_2D84p0cyk4T7X

Comment: `url+"/?id="+prop_data.id`